# Consulta usando funcion max en cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

Hola a todos como estan veran tengo esta consulta en sql

```
SELECT MAX(id_alternativa) FROM pregunta_alternativa WHERE id_pregunta = 7
```

la cual estoy haciendo en cakephp usando la funcion max del framework

```
public function register() {
    $query = $this->PreguntasAlternativas->find()
            ->select([
                'id_alternativa' => $query->func()->max(['id_alternativa'])
            ])->where(['id_pregunta' => '7']);

    $this->set('alternatives',$query);
}
```

pero me da error este es el mensaje

> Error: Call to a member function func() on null  File
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\serapp\src\Controller\PreguntasAlternativasController.php
>   Line: 14

segun veo la documentacion asi se usan sus funciones

[Funciones SQL Cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)

no se que este haciendo mal gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

estás intentando acceder a la variable `$query` sin definirla previamente.

De la documentación de **Cakephp 3**, debes hacerlo así:

```
$query = $this->PreguntasAlternativas->find();
$query->select([
            'id_alternativa' => $query->func()->max(['id_alternativa'])
        ])->where(['id_pregunta' => '7']);
```

A pesar de poder usar métodos encadenados, en este caso específico, para usar `max` DEBES setear primero la variable y luego utilizar.

Comment: Gracias si tienes razon lo probe asi Gracias!!!!